# Spark streaming UI number of records look incorrect

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to find out some logging information from spark streaming and i started with looking at the UI and the UI is always saying 0 records across the board for all the streaming batches. It is clearly incorrect as i can see it working correctly. I am using .textFileStream.

I am running locally in my machine. I can try in cluster too but i doublt this particular result will be different.

```scala
  val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("NetworkWordCount")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(20))
 val lines = ssc.textFileStream("wasbs://deadletters@deadlettertransactions.blob.core.windows.net/")

      val fullfilepath = "wasbs://newcontainer@deadlettertransactions.blob.core.windows.net/outputdata" 


      if(mydf.count() > 0)
         mydf.write.mode("append")
        .text(fullfilepath)
      }
    ssc.start()             // Start the computation
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

i expected the record processed to be more than 0 but i only see 0. look at the screenshot attached.

[image]